# Run Script with xCode Server Bot

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, bots, ci-server

I am running a on-commit Bot to build, analyze, unit tes and archive my App and it works perfectly.

I have a script (*.sh) in my porject that I want to run at the end of a success analysis. I am using xcode 7.3 now and i tried the following:

- In the trigger section call ./myscript.sh, but the bot could not find it.
- I tried to add $SCROOT, still no luck
- I tried to copy the script to bin but since the bot runs under that __xcbuild user it did not see it, and I do not want to mess with adding permission to /bin and /usr/bin

All I want is to run a script against the code the that the bot just pulled on success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source used by Xcode CI will be under a cache folder stored in an environment variable called:

$XCS_SOURCE_DIR

Your file should be somewhere under that path